# How to create a working executable jar file of a Java FX 8.0 Application

Tags: java, mysql, javafx-8

In my java fx application I used mysql as the database.I developed this application using InteliJ IDE, and for the User interface I used scene builder and also I used jfoenix,jasper and mysql libraries in this project.I created artifact and build an executable jar file correctly but I got an exception when I runs that jar file.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -jar D:\onetcoNew\onetco_pos_system\out\artifacts\onetco_pos_system\onetco_pos_system.jar
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/D:/onetcoNew/onetco_pos_system/out/artifacts/onetco_pos_system/onetco_pos_system.jar!/lk/onetco/fx/view/Login.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2848)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2661)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at lk.onetco.fx.main.Main.start(Main.java:27)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
    ... 20 more
Exception running application lk.onetco.fx.main.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you import JFXButton in your FXML?

Comment: Yes, I added the Jfoenix jar to the scene builder and add JFXButton to the UI.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could provide some code in a minimal example that demonstrates the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: it works when i change my FXML javafx version from xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171"  to xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.161". that was the problem gives me the exception.Thank you for the support